# Use Java streams to collect objects generated in a `for` loop

Tags: java, for-loop, collections, java-stream

How can we use the Java Streams approach to collecting objects generated in a `for` loop?

For example, here we generate one [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) object for each day in a month represented by [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html) by repeatedly calling [`YearMonth::atDay`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html#atDay-int-).

```
YearMonth ym = YearMonth.of( 2017 , Month.AUGUST ) ;
List<LocalDate> dates = new ArrayList<>( ym.lengthOfMonth() );
for ( int i = 1 ; i <= ym.lengthOfMonth () ; i ++ ) {
    LocalDate localDate = ym.atDay ( i );
    dates.add( localDate );
}
```

Can this be rewritten using streams?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It can be rewritten starting with an IntStream:

```
YearMonth ym = YearMonth.of(2017, Month.AUGUST);
List<LocalDate> dates =
        IntStream.rangeClosed(1, ym.lengthOfMonth())
        .mapToObj(ym::atDay)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Each integer value from the IntStream is mapped to the desired date and then the dates are collected in a list.

Comment: What controls the instantiation of the `List`? What will the concrete object behind `List` be? In the [Answer by Górkiewicz](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42285720/642706), I see we explicitly define an `ArrayList`. How is that task accomplished here? I see the doc for `toList` says “ no guarantees on the type, mutability, serializability, or thread-safety of the List returned”. Does that mean the backing concrete class used is none of my business/concern? That would be understandable and acceptable; I'm just curious.

Comment: You wanted `List<LocalDate>` and you get exactly that. If you want to explicitly define which List implementation should be used you can do also: `Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new)`

Comment: `Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new)` is good, but adds verbosity.

Comment: I understand now. [A] If I care about the backing concrete implementation of `List`, then I must provide a [`Supplier`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html) passed in a call to [`Collectors.toCollection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toCollection-java.util.function.Supplier-). In this case the Supplier takes the form of the method reference `ArrayList::new`. [B] If I do *not* care about the concrete class implementing the `List` interface, then use the shorter simpler code seen in your Answer.

Answer (score 2):

Replace your for loop with an `IntStream`:

```
YearMonth ym = YearMonth.of(2017, Month.AUGUST);
List<LocalDate> dates = new ArrayList<>(ym.lengthOfMonth());
IntStream.rangeClosed(1, ym.lengthOfMonth())
         .forEach(i -> dates.add(ym.atDay(i)));
```

Comment: Down-vote? How is this not a successful answer to the question? Please explain. This Answer earned my up-vote.

Comment: Thanks, Basil. I was not fast enough :p

Comment: one min here and there does not deserve down vote. Earned my plus one too (I am not the down voter though)

Comment: Thanks, @i_am_zero.

Answer (score 1):

In Java 9 a special method [`datesUntil`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#datesUntil-java.time.LocalDate-) is added to `LocalDate` which can generate a stream of dates:

```
LocalDate start = LocalDate.of(2017, Month.AUGUST, 1);
List<LocalDate> dates = start.datesUntil(start.plusMonths(1))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```